Fixed-effect trained model inspection in mixed-effects random forest (MERF)
I have run a Mixed-Effects Random Forest (MERF) using the python merf module, see therein example use here (see also blog post).
I have read the above and also Hajjem et al's paper, to get an idea of the method in general, and also the implementation in python.
My understanding is that the MERF model is iterative, running through until convergence in a loop that re-evaluates the fixed effects and the random effects. As put by Hajjem et al., for trees (where the forests follow the same principle):

The key idea of MERT is to dissociate  the fixed from the random
effects. It is basically an iterative call to a standard RT algorithm
within the framework of the expectation–maximization (EM) algorithm
[9,10]. At each iteration, a standard RT is built from the transformed
response data where the current estimate of the random effect
component is removed from the original response

I thought that the logical conclusion is that it is highly likely that the final model will have different feature importances and partial dependencies to the null model (fixed-effects only).
To compare models with and without random effects, I fixed the seed and ran a regular random forest. I then used that model call as the fixed effects argument to merf, as follows:
    clf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0, n_estimators=100, 
             n_jobs=-1, min_samples_split=4, max_depth=10, 
             oob_score=True, verbose=1, max_features=3)
    
clrf = MERF(fixed_effects_model=clf, max_iterations=50)

I fitted both models and looked at the feature importances. For the merf model, I retrieved this through
merfmodel.trained_fe_model.feature_importances_

, which in my understanding reflects the situation at convergence. However, the importances were identical to those for the null model (both compared to the clf fit and merfmodel.fe_model.feature_importances_). It was the same with partial dependencies.
The random effects are not trivial. The merf model had consistently improved error metrics (MSE, RMSE, MAE) and Rsq compared to the null model; and running a generalised additive model with random effects indicated the same (with, in fact, very very similar Rsq to the merf model). Further, the identical null and final random forest results situation can be reproduced for the example mentioned at the start of my question. My code to reproduce that scenario and test the initial and final models is at the bottom here.
So, why are the feature importances and partial dependencies identical between the null model and the merf model? Where lies my misunderstanding?

from merf.utils import MERFDataGenerator
from merf.merf import MERF
from merf.viz import plot_merf_training_stats
from sklearn.inspection import PartialDependenceDisplay
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dgm = MERFDataGenerator(m=.6, sigma_b=np.sqrt(4.5), sigma_e=1)
num_clusters_each_size = 20
train_sizes = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
known_sizes = [9, 27, 45, 63, 81]
new_sizes = [10, 30, 50, 70, 90]

train_cluster_sizes = MERFDataGenerator.create_cluster_sizes_array(train_sizes, num_clusters_each_size)
known_cluster_sizes = MERFDataGenerator.create_cluster_sizes_array(known_sizes, num_clusters_each_size)
new_cluster_sizes = MERFDataGenerator.create_cluster_sizes_array(new_sizes, num_clusters_each_size)

# len(train_cluster_sizes), len(known_cluster_sizes), len(new_cluster_sizes)

train, test_known, test_new, training_cluster_ids, ptev, prev = dgm.generate_split_samples(train_cluster_sizes, known_cluster_sizes, new_cluster_sizes)

# len(train), len(test_known), len(test_new)
# train.head()

X_train = train[['X_0', 'X_1', 'X_2']]
Z_train = train[['Z']]
clusters_train = train['cluster']
y_train = train['y']

mrf = MERF(max_iterations=5)
mrf.fit(X_train, Z_train, clusters_train, y_train)

mrf.trained_fe_model.feature_importances_
mrf.fe_model.feature_importances_

# Get the trained fixed effects model
fe_model = mrf.trained_fe_model
null_model = mrf.fe_model

# Compute the partial dependence for the first feature while holding all others constant (average)
display_fe_model = PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator(fe_model, X_train, [(0,1)])
display_null_model = PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator(null_model, X_train, [(0,1)])

# Create a figure with two subplots
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))

# Plot the partial dependence for the fe_model in the first subplot
display_fe_model.plot(ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('Partial dependence for fe_model')

# Plot the partial dependence for the null_model in the second subplot
display_null_model.plot(ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('Partial dependence for null_model')

plt.show()  

